# OSX 10.10.3 Update - App Store icon image missing

Tags: macos, software-update, icon

After installing the 10.10.3 update I noticed my App Store no longer has an icon image, it's just a blank space now in the Applications folder and dock. This persists after a reboot and I'd like my icon back.

Clicking on the App Store text loads it just fine, just missing the icon, anyone else come across this or know how I workaround this other than a Time machine restore?

Answer (score 2):

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6983727

Resolved it from this workaround:

1. Click informations on the blank icon.
2. Click on the library icon in the left corner of the informations window and copy it.
3. Open Preview.
4. Paste the copied icon and save it on desktop.
5. Now, just drag and drop the new icon to the old icon of the informations window of the broken Library icon.